# Integrating DataTables plugin with django framework

Tags: django, datatable, datatables, django-rest-framework

I am a beginner in django framework and DataTables. Currently, I am trying to load a jquery DataTable with the data coming back from the server. I have built an api using django REST framework to pass the data to DataTables. However, I am not able to load the DataTable from the json data from the server. Please find below my code snippets and pleas tell me if I am missing anything.

the index.html looks like following.

```
<table id="packages_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#packages_table').dataTable({
            ajax: 'http://127.0.0.1:3434/user/',
            columns: [
                { "data": "username"},
                { "data": "first_name"},
                { "data": "email"},
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

urls.py, where I have defined the viewset, serializer and router looks like this.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email', 'is_staff')

# ViewSets define the view behavior.

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer


# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user', UserViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include(datagrid_urls)),
    #configure to use the browsable API by adding REST framework's login and logout views
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]  + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And, below is the json data from the url.

```
[
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3434/user/2/",
        "username": "morgoth",
        "first_name": "morgoth",
        "email": "duke.valafar@gmail.com",
        "is_staff": true
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3434/user/3/",
        "username": "anna",
        "first_name": "",
        "email": "anna@anna.com",
        "is_staff": false
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3434/user/4/",
        "username": "adam",
        "first_name": "",
        "email": "ada@abc.com",
        "is_staff": false
    }
]
```

And here is my [debug bookmarklet](http://debug.datatables.net/enotiw)

Comment: DataTables has a very specific format that it is expecting, I'm fairly certain you can't match it with DRF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

You need to use the following initialization code to match your data structure:

```
$('#packages_table').dataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3434/user/',
        dataSrc: '' 
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "username"},
        { "data": "first_name"},
        { "data": "email"},
    ]
});
```

From the [dataSrc](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option description:

> Note that if your Ajax source simply returns an array of data to
>   display, rather than an object, set this parameter to be an empty
>   string.

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // AJAX emulation for demonstration only
  $.mockjax({
    url: 'arrays.txt',
    responseTime: 200,
    response: function(settings) {
      this.responseText = [
        {
          "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3434/user/2/",
          "username": "morgoth",
          "first_name": "morgoth",
          "email": "duke.valafar@gmail.com",
          "is_staff": true
        }, {
          "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3434/user/3/",
          "username": "anna",
          "first_name": "",
          "email": "anna@anna.com",
          "is_staff": false
        }, {
          "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3434/user/4/",
          "username": "adam",
          "first_name": "",
          "email": "ada@abc.com",
          "is_staff": false
        }
      ]
    }
  });

  var table = $('#packages_table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: "arrays.txt",
      dataSrc: ""
    },
    columns: [
        { "data": "username" },
        { "data": "first_name"},
        { "data": "email"}
    ]    
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

  <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://vitalets.github.com/x-editable/assets/mockjax/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <table id="packages_table" class="display">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried with the modification as you suggested, but it did not work. I think I am quite close and missing something very basic. I can render the table in the browser, only the data is not loading.

Comment: @valafar, added the demo to show that the code works, inspect the connections in the Network tab and make sure that you received the data from `http://127.0.0.1:3434/user/`.

Comment: the ajax code is not getting executed in my case. I took a look in the developer console and there is no XHR request. Any idea what I could have been missing?

Comment: @valafar, try adding `dataType: "jsonp"` after `dataSrc: ''` as  `dataSrc: '', dataType: "jsonp"`.

Comment: I have already tried that. Also tried with `cache: false,` but that did not work as well. I have updated my question with datatables debug bookmarklet result. Can you please check once and let me know if it looks good?

Comment: @valafar, is this a cross-domain request? Is HTML loaded from `http://127.0.0.1:3434` as well? Do you see any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2):

Gyrocode.com was absolutely correct about mentioning the `dataSrc` field. However, even that did not work as a solution. After a lot of trial and error, I found that I was using DataTables version 1.9.4, whereas in 1.10 version the syntax is very different to call the ajax function.

Hence to make it work, `ajax` field has to be replaced by `sAjaxSource`. Detailed reference to this conversion is covered in this [link](http://www.datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert).
However, the best solution, is, of-course to update the DataTables version to 1.10.

I would like to mention [DataTables Debugger](https://debug.datatables.net/) tool, which really helped me to debug this issue and I would like to recommend it to people who might get stuck in future while debugging DataTables related issue.