# Django datatables from dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, datatable

I am struggling to handle data tables in django project. My idea is to read a CSV file and store data in dictionary and then render it, which is working perfectly till now. But I want to make my display like in this image [image: table]

I have gone through [this following example](http://django-listable.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) but seems like it is perfect for database which I am not doing now. So I don't have any models.py in my app but my views.py will display this following dictionary:

```
{'PEP2012090602': [['P09958', 'FURIN', 'Furin', 'MLDGEVTDAVEAR', 'Homo sapiens'], ['P23188', 'Furin', 'Furin', 'MLDGEVTDAVEAR', 'Mus musculus'], ['P23377', 'Furin', 'Furin', 'MLDGEVTDAVEAR', 'Rattus norvegicus'], ['P29119', 'furin', 'Furin-1', 'MLDGEVTDAVEAR', 'Xenopus laevis'], ['Q28193', 'FURIN', 'Furin', 'MLDGEVTDAVEAR', 'Bos taurus']]}
```

I am really new in django so I would appreciate if anyone kindly suggest me how to do or some tutorial where people already worked on this kind of example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I have solved that problem just printing each element of my dictionary in template using [following example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

the way I would do it is don't use the django-listable module but instead go with django-rest-framework (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) build your serialized object starting from the csv containing your data then use the normal Datatables with a normal JSON load.

For the implementation of this you can also refer to this [Integrating DataTables plugin with django framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502909/integrating-datatables-plugin-with-django-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to send an object to view if the object will not be used to render that view. I think it would be better to use REST. In Django, `django-rest-framework` and `django-tasty-pie` are good solutions. You could also check [django-datatable](https://github.com/shymonk/django-datatable) [django-datatable-view](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-datatables-view).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.....I have tried django-datatable which seems like easier to understand but didn't workout for me (I need to read their dcomentation). I will try to use other options lets see how it works in my case!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in writing the data to models. Options you have are as below:

**Option #1:**

Then one you way is that you pass the entire data to your html template, then write a code there to read the dictionary/list that you are sending.

Templates documentation can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/

**Option #2:**

use Django-tables2 for generating your tables on html page.
https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/